# How do I use { merge:true } in Firebase without overwriting nested fields?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I used **{ merge:true }** to avoid **overwritten** data

when I registered it and it still gets **overwritten**. Is the usage wrong?

Is there anything else I need to add?

```
  const board = collection(db, "board");
  const setBoard = async () =>
    await setDoc(
      doc(board, "items"),
      {
        name: name,
        price: price,
        category: kind,
        size: {
          default: {
            small: size.includes("s") === true && "s",
            medium: size.includes("m") === true && "m",
            large: size.includes("l") === true && "l",
            extralarge: size.includes("xl") === true && "xl",
            twoextralarge: size.includes("xxl") === true && "xxl",
          },
        },
        description: description,
      },
      { merge: true }
    );

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setBoard();
    console.log(board);
    ...
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

      ...

      <button>제품 등록하기</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**before**

[image]

**after**

[image]

**want**

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to be very specific about the behavior you're observing that's different than what you expect.  We can't see the contents of the document before or after this code is run, so we don't know what you've observing and how that's different than what you expect. Are you asking about a specific field?  Which one(s)?  Please be specific.

Comment: Do you want to have several times the same type of data (of object) that is in the blue box #1? If this is the case you would need to use a field of type Array or of type Map to save a set of objects

Comment: Yes, I would like to add a blue box with a different value in the form of a #1 blue box
But, I have no idea

Comment: When you specified a value for the `size` field, it overwrites everything nested under the field.  If you want to update only certain nested fields, you need to use dot notation to call out the specific nested field on its own.  See also this post: https://medium.com/feedflood/update-data-in-cloud-firestore-merge-true-in-set-operation-166703040de